# How to import a variable from a JS file in another JS file that uses Vue CDN? - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, cdn

I'm new to Vue, and been trying to import a variable that consists of API key necessary for my app.js where Vue CDN is used.
But I received this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier app.js:1

Everything else works fine, only I have issue with importing.

The preview of my code:

```
//---config.js---


export const key = 'someKey';


//---app.js---

import key from './config.js'

new Vue({
  ...,
  components: {
    key
  },
  ...
```

P.S. is there a way to make it work without using Vue CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use import/export you should add `type="module"` in script tag in html. Like this.

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

And as you used export instead of default export when importing use:

```
import {key} from './config.js'
```

Comment: So I had to add ' type="module" ' to both of them? I did so. And it worked. I also missed to add '.js' extension to my config in import part. Thank you so much. Wish you good luck by your own debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

Where are you using import export statement? (Chrome, Firefox and etc). To understand where import export statement work you should check Browser compatibility.
[image]

Comment: I'm using Chrome v73.